# Проблема с методом map в React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Вот код:

```
{projects.map(project=>{
    <div key={project.id} >
        <div>
            <img src={project.image} alt="" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <p>{project.text}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
})}
```

Вот js "база данных"
Проблема в том что метод map работает но ничего на страницу не выводит

Я в начале делал это через Props(он тоже не работал), но решил проверить и убрал его. Фишка в том что даже vscode при наведении на project показывает данные из js. Но всё равно ничего не выводится

Comment: Ваши стрелочные функции ничего не возвращают

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете стрелочную функцию, после чего открыли скобки. Это значит, что вы должны прописать тело метода, и если хотите что либо вернуть, то прописать return. Вам надо опять же либо прописать return, либо убрать скобки:

```
{projects.map(
  project => (
    <div key={project.id}>
      <div>
        <img src={project.image} alt="" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <p>{project.text}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
)}
```

*(дополнительная **фигурная** скобка поставлена для удобства)*